# Assign columns to grouping variable for use with ordihull plotting

Tags: r, multi-dimensional-scaling

I have a dataframe consisting of dissimilarity ratings for pairs of 12 nations, and what I wish to do is essentially divide the columns (the nations) into three different groups (not combining their scores).

I am performing a non-metric multidimensional scaling, so I would like to plot the dissimilarity ratings with convex hulls according to these three groups.

I know the code for making the plots, all I am missing is the grouping variable that is needed, and I cannot for the life of me figure out how to create it.

```
     Brazil Congo Cuba Egypt France India Israel Japan China UdSSR  USA Yugoslavia

1    0.00  4.83 5.28  3.44   4.72  4.50   3.83  3.50  2.39  3.06 5.39       3.17
2    4.83  0.00 4.56  5.00   4.00  4.83   3.33  3.39  4.00  3.39 2.39       3.50
3    5.28  4.56 0.00  5.17   4.11  4.00   3.61  2.94  5.50  5.44 3.17       5.11
4    3.44  5.00 5.17  0.00   4.78  5.83   4.67  3.83  4.39  4.39 3.33       4.28
5    4.72  4.00 4.11  4.78   0.00  3.44   4.00  4.22  3.67  5.06 5.94       4.72
6    4.50  4.83 4.00  5.83   3.44  0.00   4.11  4.50  4.11  4.50 4.28       4.00
7    3.83  3.33 3.61  4.67   4.00  4.11   0.00  4.83  3.00  4.17 5.94       4.44
8    3.50  3.39 2.94  3.83   4.22  4.50   4.83  0.00  4.17  4.61 6.06       4.28
9    2.39  4.00 5.50  4.39   3.67  4.11   3.00  4.17  0.00  5.72 2.56       5.06
10   3.06  3.39 5.44  4.39   5.06  4.50   4.17  4.61  5.72  0.00 5.00       6.67
11   5.39  2.39 3.17  3.33   5.94  4.28   5.94  6.06  2.56  5.00 0.00       3.56
12   3.17  3.50 5.11  4.28   4.72  4.00   4.44  4.28  5.06  6.67 3.56       0.00
```

This is probably a frustratingly simple command, but I am truly lost.

Comment: What exactly is your desired output here? What does the data-frame you want to plot with look like?